# Standalone doesn't place properly the content

Tags: luatex, standalone, pdfcrop

I'm trying to create many small pdf graphics such as this one:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.markings,math,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\tablenode}[2]{\tikz[baseline=(#1.base),remember picture]\node[inner sep=1pt,name=#1]{#2};}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}   
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0mm,title=Sample data, colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black]
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
            id & Type & Date \\ 
            \hline
            1 & \tablenode{1}{A} & 1980 \\ 
            1 & \tablenode{2}{B} & 1991 \\ 
            2 & \tablenode{3}{C} & 1978 \\ 
            2 & \tablenode{4}{A} & 1990 \\ 
            2 & \tablenode{5}{A} & 1998 \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, 
hor/.style={shorten <=1pt, shorten >=2pt, -{Triangle[angle=80:4pt]}, color=green!60!black!85, line width=2pt},
hor2/.style={shorten <=1pt, shorten >=2pt, -{Triangle[angle=80:4pt]}, color=red!70!black!85!, line width=2pt}]
\draw [hor] (1) -- (2);
\draw [hor] (3) -- (4);
\draw [hor] (4) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Luatex creates a pdf with size A4 and I later use pdfcrop.exe to remove the margins.

[image]

But I would prefer to do it on a single step, with standalone, but it doesn't work.

I've tried with:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.markings,math,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\tablenode}[2]{\tikz[baseline=(#1.base),remember picture]\node[inner sep=1pt,name=#1]{#2};}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    ...
\end{document}
```

But the image is not properly cut.
[image]

I've also tried with the solutions proposed here:
[Problem with content location with standalone package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103103/problem-with-content-location-with-standalone-package)

```
%\documentclass[multi=minipage, border=0]{standalone}
```

or

```
%\documentclass[multi=varwidth, border=0]{standalone}
```

or

```
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
```

but it even worse
[image]

Comment: I've icluded pictures showing it.  I would like to get the whole table as in my first picture (manually cropped), but I just get broken tables or splitted on several pages. I mean I would like to get the same result as in my first picture but using standalone or some automatic method.

Comment: In the second example, changing the width of the `minipage` environment from `0.25\linewidth` to `0.4\linewidth`would stop the lopping off of the material in the third column.

Comment: @Mico OK, now it works a little bit better but still has some white margins beyond the limits of the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding spaces with the unprotected endlines in

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
```

which you can avoid by placing the material before `\begin{document}`.

You can also avoid guessing the width with `hbox`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.markings,math,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\tablenode}[2]{\tikz[baseline=(#1.base),remember picture]\node[inner sep=1pt,name=#1]{#2};}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox,boxsep=0mm,title=Sample data, colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black]
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
            id & Type & Date \\
            \hline
            1 & \tablenode{1}{A} & 1980 \\
            1 & \tablenode{2}{B} & 1991 \\
            2 & \tablenode{3}{C} & 1978 \\
            2 & \tablenode{4}{A} & 1990 \\
            2 & \tablenode{5}{A} & 1998 \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}% <---- don't forget
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
hor/.style={shorten <=1pt, shorten >=2pt, -{Triangle[angle=80:4pt]}, color=green!60!black!85, line width=2pt},
hor2/.style={shorten <=1pt, shorten >=2pt, -{Triangle[angle=80:4pt]}, color=red!70!black!85!, line width=2pt}]
\draw [hor] (1) -- (2);
\draw [hor] (3) -- (4);
\draw [hor] (4) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do we use that strange % after \end{tcolorbox} ?